# How to check how much data send to server with three20?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I want make some progress bar in my application with **three20** library when sending data to server. Can someone help me with this?

I am using

```
- (void)requestDidStartLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request
```

and

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. 
You must call
`[request send];` 
to call this delegate function:

```
- (void)requestDidUploadData:(TTURLRequest *)request
{
    float progress = request.totalBytesLoaded / (float)request.totalBytesExpected;

    HUD.progress = progress;
    HUD.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Progress %d%%", (int)(progress*100)];
}
```

if you call `sendSynchronously` data will send but you can't get `totalBytesLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement

```
- (void)requestDidUploadData:(TTURLRequest *)request
```

and check the `totalBytesLoaded` and `totalBytesExpected` properties, per http://api.three20.info/protocol_t_t_u_r_l_request_delegate-p.php#a9c831806650a4b887f5cf963f6bbba1c.

Comment: I have used like this: `- (void)requestDidUploadData:(TTURLRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"%d %d %d", request.totalBytesLoaded, request.totalContentLength, request.totalBytesDownloaded);
}` and it is not called at all.

Comment: You've verified you've set the delegate correctly, as well as that you are actually uploading the data? I don't know what else to suggest I've not used three20 in years :(

Comment: Yes, delegate setuped correctly because `- (void)requestDidStartLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request` and `- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request` functions are called when uploading started and finished.